# How to reset configuration in EmojiCompat?

Tags: android, emoji

I want to reset `EmojiCompat` configuration but when I am trying to reset it shows me an error like

[image]
it says same group id need for the use this method so, now how can I reset `EmojiCompat` I want to give user define configuration like replace all emoji or not.